# How to choose GPS setup?

Tags: gps, mapping

I need some advice on choosing a GPS setup to map estuarine habitats in the field.

Our SA estuaries are often very narrow (1 to 2 km wide) and habitats are  small.
We distinguish between supratidal salt marsh, intertidal salt marsh, reeds and sedges, among other habitats. Reeds and sedges often form a very narrow band along an estuary.  Accuracy needs to be as close as possible to 1 to 2 KM, perhaps even better.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! This question is out of scope for our site, since the connection to computational science isn't obvious. GIS might be a better fit, or at least they might know a better forum for this question; Biology might be another good forum. It's not clear to me whether either of those sites will accept your question, though, so you should ask moderators on those sites to see if your question is on-topic.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/how-to-choose-gps-setup; found it just after migration.

Answer (score 0):

Any modern GPS should have accuracy of at least <10 meters. For some Garmin units, there is an 'average' function which increases the accuracy even more by taking many measurements over a period of time.

Comment: Can you list some of the Garmin units that have this functionality?

Comment: I'd recommend just looking for any GPS that is advertised for 'trekking,' and avoid those made for driving. There are literally dozens of models, just look for the spatial accuracy spec.